# Change font in colorkey legend in R levelplot

Tags: r, levelplot

I have the next plot with increased ticks and axis label font size:

```
library(lattice)
x <- rep(seq(6,15,by=1), each=20)
y <- rep(seq(0,0.95,by=0.05), 10)
z <- x*y
levelplot(z ~ x * y,
          scales=list(x=list(at=seq(6,15,1), cex=2), y=list(at=seq(0,0.9,0.1), cex=2)),
          xlab=list(label="x", cex=2),
          ylab=list(label="y", cex=2))
```

But how can I increase the font size in the colorkey legend as well?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use argument `colorkey` in `levelplot`:

```
library(lattice)
x <- rep(seq(6,15,by=1), each=20)
y <- rep(seq(0,0.95,by=0.05), 10)
z <- x*y

ckey <- list(labels=list(cex=2))

levelplot(z ~ x * y,
      scales=list(x=list(at=seq(6,15,1), cex=2), y=list(at=seq(0,0.9,0.1), cex=2)),
      xlab=list(label="x", cex=2),
      ylab=list(label="y", cex=2), 
      colorkey=ckey)
```

[image]